# How can I populate the fields after running the aggregation mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to populate the fields in the result that I got from running the `$geoNear` aggregation but I don't know how can I do it. I tried `$lookup` but it gave me the same result.

```
const users = await locations.aggregate([
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: req.body.coordinates,
          },
          maxDistance: req.body.maxDistance,
          distanceField: "dist.calculated",
          spherical: true,
        },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "userId",    // getting empty array of users
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "users",
        },
      },  // getting all users data
  {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          name: 1,   
          profession: 1,
        },
      }, // only getting `_id`
      },
    ]);
```

Result:

```
{
        {
            "_id": "63555c4f29820cf3c7667eb5",
            "userId": "63555c2629820cf3c7667eac",
            "location": {
                "coordinates": [
                    2.346688,
                    48.858888
                ],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "createdAt": "2022-10-23T15:22:55.820Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-10-23T16:08:59.979Z",
            "__v": 2,
            "dist": {
                "calculated": 42.95013302539912
            }
        }
}
```

I want to populate the `name` field from the `users` schema and to do so I have used the `ref` of the `users` schema in the `locations` schema.

users schema:

```
{
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      index: true,
    },
}
```

location Schema:

```
 {
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "users",
      required: true,
    },
    location: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Point"],
        default: "Point",
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        default: [0, 0],
      },
    },
  },
```

How can I populate fields in my aggregation result?

Also, How can I remove all the fields and output the names and email only from the `users` schema?

Comment: Can you add sample documents for both collections and the expected result?

Comment: I have added both `locations` and `users` sample schemas.

Comment: Can you also add the `$lookup` stage you tried to add. Usually this should work using a simple lookup based on the userId property.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus added `$lookup` stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include your `$lookup` stage as following:

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "users",
    localField: "userId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "user",
  }
},
{
  "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$user",
        0
      ]
    }
  }
}, 
{
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    name: 1,
    profession: 1
  }
}
```

It seems like you tried to match an `ObjectId` to a String (property `name`), which will never match. Using the aggregation step above you should receive a populated user array containing exactly one entry. After that you can project the result and transform the array to a plain object (if needed).

Comment: I have also tried the same thing before but I am getting every fields of users instead of `name` and & `email`.

Comment: How can I manipulate the result and only output the `name` & `email` instead of the users' details and location details?

Comment: added aggregation steps to my answer. You should first replace your root documents with the populated user data. Afterwards the projection on user properties should work as expected.